# error in SQL syntax near primary key

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `bank`.`Customer_registrationTable` 
( `Account_no` INT NOT NULL , 
  `Name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
  `Address` INT(100) NOT NULL , 
  `Account_type` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
  `Gender` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
  `DOB` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
  `Password` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
  `Date` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
  `Age` INT(10) NOT NULL , 
  `Previous_Balance` DOUBLE(20) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`Account_no`(30))) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

after writing this I got problem that said,

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`Account_no`(30))) WHERE  ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 1

Comment: instead of `PRIMARY KEY (`Account_no`(30))` just **PRIMARY KEY (`Account_no`)**

Comment: Remove the age column. It's daft and redundant. Store dates as dates. Store money as DECIMAL.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `bank`.`Customer_registrationTable` 
( `Account_no` INT NOT NULL , 
  `Name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
  `Address` INT(100) NOT NULL , 
  `Account_type` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
  `Gender` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
  `DOB` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
  `Password` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
  `Date` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
  `Age` INT(10) NOT NULL , 
  `Previous_Balance` DOUBLE NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`Account_no`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

PRIMARY KEY (`Account_no`) should not have (20)
`Previous_Balance` DOUBLE NOT NULL should not have (20), it should like DOUBLE(20, 2)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer_registrationtable` (
 `Account_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Address` int(100) NOT NULL,
`Account_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Gender` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`DOB` datetime NOT NULL,
`Password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Date` datetime NOT NULL,
`Age` int(10) NOT NULL,
`Previous_Balance` double(20,2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Account_no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```